# Game of Life memory issue: 3D Array (generations, x, y). Possible to minimize memory usage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory, memory-management

EDIT: Some helpful replies makes me realize I forgot to include a crucial detail. I am also checking for oscillations, meaning I have to store information for every generation.

I'm recreating the Game of Life in JavaScript and need a 3D array. As I understand, I have to declare the size of an array before I can start filling it. This is unfortunate because I can't know how many generations the game will last for. If I set it to low, the Game may stop abruptly. If I set it to high, the browser may crash from filling up the memory. This is my code for declaring the 3D matrix.

```
    cellMatrix = new Array();

    function declareMatrix() {

        for (var g = 0; g < maxGenerations; g++) {

            cellMatrix[g] = new Array();

            for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {

                cellMatrix[g][x] = new Array();

                for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {

                    cellMatrix[g][x][y] = new Array();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Main Question: is there a more memory-efficient way to do it?

Bonus question with no single correct answer (sorry): How much memory usage is too much?

Comment: If you have 16 cells, you _have_ to use 16 memory locations. You can't optimize your array storage.

Comment: No, JavaScript arrays are dynamic and grow/shrink automatically. Even in your example code you not "declaring array sizes" anywher.

Comment: did you ever measure the value of 'maxGeneration'?

Comment: the value of maxGenerations was defined by me, before I learned from the answers here that I didn't need to define the size of an array first. Some cognitive fallacy I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why would you have to declare the size of an array before you can start filling it?

you can always extend the matrix with new items. well, maybe you could tell us what you want to do with the matrix.

too much memory usage in my opinion is more than 100 MB for something not too complex. but maybe you are more worried about the size of the array, it depends on what you store in it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a more memory-efficient way to do it: use a two-dimensional array and compute the next generation on the fly. If your use case requires skipping back and forth a lot, you could also maybe store every, say, thousandth generation and use those as starting points. An efficient algorithm like [HashLife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashlife) might help with this if you’re not already using one.

Most everything is a time/code complexity/memory tradeoff, actually. There’s always storing each cell as a bit instead of 4+ bytes.

> As I understand, I have to declare the size of an array before I can start filling it.

Not in JavaScript.